# Blazorise Bootstrap Responsive Classes

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, blazor, blazorise

When using the `Blazorise` `bootstrap` grid components how do you set the responsive layout options using `ColumnSize` property.  I want the column to be size 12 on small screens.

```
        <Row>
            <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is3">
                <StatusSelectListComponent @bind-Text="@_item.Status" OnSave="@ItemEditSave" OnCancel="@ItemEditCancel"></StatusSelectListComponent>
            </Column>
        </Row>
```

Answer (score 5):

`Blazorise` allows you to chain size values together and has mapped the properties to the bootstrap classes as follows:

```
╔══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ Blazorise    ║ Bootstrap ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ OnMobile     ║ col-xs    ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ OnTablet     ║ col-sm    ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ OnDesktop    ║ col-md    ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ OnWidescreen ║ col-lg    ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ OnFullHD     ║ col-xl    ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

So the `Blazorise ColumnSize` property would look like this:

```
    <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is12.OnTablet.Is12.OnMobile.Is3.OnDesktop.Is3.OnWidescreen.Is3.OnFullHD">
    </Column>
```

The resulting html would be:

```
<div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" style=""></div>
```

Comment: Here are the docs related to this: https://blazorise.com/docs/helpers/utilities/